# Delete image on database delete symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

[Symfony Forms](http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/08/16/symfony2-jobeet-day-10-the-forms/)

I have this all working correctly. One thing that I am not sure is how to delete the image that is uploaded in the uploads folder when the associated entry in the database is deleted.

I really just need an idea on how to do it to get headed in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are both correct I did a var dump on the code that was in the entity...

```
 /**
 * @ORM\PostRemove
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }    
}
```

if file exists $file was showing an empty variable. In the upload it saves the variable as $logo

I changed the code to the following

```
 /**
 * @ORM\PostRemove
 */
public function removeUpload() {
     // ** Original Code used file but logo has the name in it.

     if(file_exists($this->getAbsolutePath())) {
         if ($this->getUploadRootDir() . $this->logo = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($this->logo);
        }
    } 
}
```

It now deletes the file correctly. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

In your delete action, you would have to delete the file manually. I assume you will be storing the file path in the database, so this should be relatively easy.

```
$path = ....//query db to get the path to the file
if($path){
    unlink($path);
}

//now you can delete the record in the database
```

See [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) for deleting a file

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably searching for are [Doctrine2 Lifecycles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks). Just add a method to your entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove
 */
public function deleteImage()
{
    // unlink your image and what not.
}
```

Also don't forget the `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` annotation for your entity class.